# the derivative of the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f (x) = x^z$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

I want to show that the derivative of the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $f (x) = x^z$ with $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is $zx^{z-1}$. For that I tried to apply the definition, let $h\neq 0$ then
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{(x+h)^z-x^z}{h}
$$
but how can I develop the expression $(x+h)^z$ to get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like, the calculation can be reduced to the derivative of the exponential function as follows:

$\log x^z = z\log x$, so $x^z = \exp(z\log x)$. Applying the chain rule gives the derivative as
$$
\frac d{dx} x^z = \frac zx \exp(z\log x) = zx^{z-1}.
$$.

Comment: $\log$ denotes any determination of the logarithm?

Comment: It's log base $e$.

Comment: @Made You can choose any branch of the log in the domain of interest. And indeed, it is the natural log (to the base $e$).

Comment: To my knowledge, the natural logarithm is defined on R. no? is the natural logarithm in the complex case the main determination of the logarithm ?

Comment: @Made That's a very valid question. Since the exponential function is not injective, it is not possible to define a log function on the set of non-zero complex numbers. However, it is possible to define (several) functions $\log: U\to \mathbb C$ for any simply connected domain $U\subset \mathbb C^*$. All of these satisfy $\frac d{dz} \log z=1/z$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm